# transfer db from one heroku app to another faster

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Is there a faster way to transfer my production database to a test app?

Currently I'm doing a `heroku db:pull` to my local machine then `heroku db:push --app testapp` but this is becoming time consuming.  I have some seed data but it is not nearly as accurate as simply testing with my real-world data.  And since they're both stored on a neighboring AWS cloud, there must be a faster way to move the data?

I thought about using a heroku bundle, but I noticed the animate command is gone?

```
bundles:animate <bundle>     # animate a bundle into a new app
```

Comment: Sidenote: Heroku bundles and Bundler are separate and unrelated concepts.

Comment: ah yeah, i wasn't even thinking about that possible mix-up when i wrote it.

Answer (score 86):

It's quite common to migrate databases between staging, testing and production environments for Rails Apps. And `heroku db:pull/push` is painfully slow. The best way I have found so far is using [Heroku PG Backups add-on](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups) and [it's free](http://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups). I followed following steps to migrate 
production database to staging server:

1) Create the backup for the production-app db

```
heroku pg:backups capture --app production-app
```

This will generate b001 backup file from the main database (usually production db in database.yml)

2) To view all the backups (OPTIONAL)

```
heroku pg:backups --app production-app
```

3) Now use the pg:backups restore command to populate staging server database from the last backup file on production server

```
heroku pg:backups restore $(heroku pg:backups public-url --app production-app) DATABASE_URL --app staging-app
```

Remember that restore is a destructive operation, it will delete existing data before replacing it with the contents of the backup file.

Comment: Quick  note, this process does not drop and recreate the schema.  This means if you have extra tables in staging, they will still be there after the restore.  You need to do a db:schema:load (or other commands) to recreate the schema if you want tables to disappear.

Comment: I get !    Backup not found when doing this operation. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: @patrick You can leave out DATABASE if your staging app only has 1 database.

Comment: Its also a good idea to put the app in maintenance mode before doing that. For a while there a no database constrains active and you can end up with corrupted data.

Comment: I always failed doing this. Error: "!    Unknown database: <database dump URL>"

Comment: Oh I know why, the arguments' order is incorrect. Should be:
''heroku pg:backups restore `heroku pgbackups:url --app production-app` DATABASE_URL --app staging-app''

Comment: The syntax for these commands have changed again. https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/3/11/pgbackups-levels-up

Answer (score 14):

So things are even easier now .. checkout the transfer command as part of pgbackups

```
heroku pgbackups:transfer HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK sushi-staging::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE -a sushi
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#4b-alternative-transfer-data-between-applications

This has worked beautifully for me taking production code back to my staging site.

Comment: Yea, but this will destroy original db. I would use pg:copy instead

Comment: `pg:backups restore` destroys original db too (see [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups#restoring-backups)): "Unlike with the previous pgbackups commands, you cannot restore a partial backup into an existing database. When you run pg:backups restore, all data is deleted from the target database before restoring the backup."

Comment: @gabe `pg:backups restore` does NOT destroy the original DB. The quote you mentioned says that it will delete all data from the *target* DB, not the source.

Answer (score 11):

Update for mid-2015...

The pgbackups add-on has been deprecated. No more `pgbackups:transfer`. `pg:copy` is ideal for this scenario.

To copy a database from *yourapp* (example db name: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL to *yourapp_staging* (example db name: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL)

```
# turn off the web dynos in staging
heroku maintenance:on -a yourapp-staging

# if you have non-web-dynos, do them too
heroku ps:scale worker=0 -a yourapp-staging

# backup the staging database if you are paranoid like me (optional)
heroku pg:backups capture -a yourapp-staging

# execute the copy to splat over the top of the staging database
heroku pg:copy yourapp::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK_URL HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_WHITE_URL -a yourapp-staging
```

Then when it's complete, turn staging back on:

```
# this is if you have workers, change '1' to whatever
heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a yourapp-staging

heroku maintenance:off -a yourapp-staging
```

Reminder: you can use `heroku pg:info -a yourapp-staging` (and yourapp) to get the database constants.

(source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrade-with-pg-copy-default)

Answer (score 11):

The correct answer has changed again as of March 11, 2015.

```
heroku pg:backups restore $(heroku pg:backups public-url --app myapp-production) DATABASE_URL --app myapp-staging
```

Note specifically that the argument is now `public-url`.

https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2015/3/11/pgbackups-levels-up

Answer (score 0):

```
psql -h test_host -c 'drop database test_db_name; create database test_db_name;'

pg_dump -h production_host production_db_name | psql -h test_host test_db_name`
```

This can be done on `production_host` or on `test_host` — will work both ways.

Comment: This will be very slow unless both of the databases and the machine running `pg_dump ...| psql...` are in the same EC2 region.

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested this, but it might work.

Do this to get the URL of your source database:

```
heroku console "ENV['DATABASE_URL']" --app mysourceapp
```

Then try executing `db:push` with that.

```
heroku db:push database_url_from_before --app mytargetapp
```

This might not work if Heroku doesn't allow access to the DB machines from outside their network, which is probably the case. You could, perhaps, try using taps (gem that heroku db commands use internally) from within your app code somewhere (maybe a rake task). This would be even faster than the above approach because everything stays completely within AWS.

**Edit:**

Here's an (admittedly hacky) way to do what I described above:

Grab the database URL as in the first code snippet above. Then from a rake task (you could do it on console but you risk running into the 30 second timeout limit on console commands), execute a shell command to taps (couldn't easily determine whether it's possible to use taps directly from Ruby; all docs show use of the CLI):

```
`taps pull database_url_from_source_app #{ENV['DATABASE_URL']}`
```

The backticks are important; this is how Ruby denotes a shell command, which taps is. Hopefully the taps command is accessible from the app. This avoids the problem of accessing the database machine from outside Heroku, since you're running this command from within your app.

Comment: Taps has been deprecated for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku enables you to fork existing applications in production. Use heroku fork to copy an existing application, including add-ons, config vars, and Heroku Postgres data.

Follow the instructions on Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fork-app

Comment: This is nigh unusable on apps of any significant scale. It's expensive and takes forever to copy your (potentially many) databases.

Answer (score 0):

Update for mid-2016...

Heroku now have a `--fast` flag when creating forks, however they will be up to 30 hours out-of-date.

`$ heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-4 --fork HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL --fast --app sushi`

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-fork#fork-fast-option