# How do I transfer production database to staging on Heroku using pgbackups? Getting error

Tags: postgresql, heroku

On Heroku, I am trying to copy the production database into my staging app using the pgbackups addon. I followed the instructions on the addon page: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pgbackups

First I captured the DB:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture --app production-app
```

That worked:

```
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE (DATABASE_URL)  ----backup--->  b238

Capturing... done
Storing... done
```

However when I try to restore it on the staging app:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app production-app` --remote staging
```

I get the following error message:

```
DATABASE_URL does not match any of your databases
 !    Could not resolve database DATABASE
 !    
 !    Available databases:
```

I have also tried typing in the full URL:

```
 heroku pgbackups:url b238 --app production-app
 heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE "https://s3.amazonaws.com/..." --remote staging
```

and also tried naming the app (instead of --remote staging):

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app production-app` --app staging-app
```

None of these worked. It's interesting to note that the error message says there are no "Available databases". I'm assuming it is referring to the staging app which is indeed empty. If I type:

```
heroku pgbackups
```

I get:

```
 !    No backups. Capture one with `heroku pgbackups:capture`.
```

To find the available backups (production), I need to type:

```
heroku pgbackups --app production-app
```

and I get the list of current backups. I don't know if this is normal or even if it is related to the problem, but I thought I should mention it.

I have read and tried every answer here on SO but nothing worked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 100):

Update for mid-2017 (stealing from *Takehiro Mouri*'s answer - simplify the DATABSE_NAME part)

Update for mid-2015...

The pgbackups add-on has been deprecated. No more `pgbackups:transfer`.

To copy a database from *yourapp* to *yourapp_staging*:

```
# turn off the web dynos in staging
heroku maintenance:on -a yourapp-staging

# if you have non-web-dynos, do them too
heroku ps:scale worker=0 -a yourapp-staging

# backup the staging database if you are paranoid like me (optional)
heroku pg:backups capture -a yourapp-staging

# execute the copy
heroku pg:copy your-app::DATABASE_URL DATABASE_URL -a yourapp-staging
```

Then when it's complete, turn staging back on:

```
# this is if you have workers, change '1' to whatever
heroku ps:scale worker=1 -a yourapp-staging

heroku maintenance:off -a yourapp-staging
```

(source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#upgrade-with-pg-copy-default)

Comment: Does this new process (as opposed to applying an already generated backup from prod to staging) put any additional pressure on the primary DB during `heroku pg:copy`?

Comment: My use-case is not large enough to determine that. I can't see anything in their documentation about it (beyond estimating the process will take 3 minutes per GB of data).

Given that no existing backup is required, you'd have to assume that the process puts a read IO load on the source database for most of the period of the copy.

Comment: I couldn't easily spot the database name in the output of pg:info.  Is it the "Add-on" field?

Comment: ... answer: yes it is.  The db names don't look like those colors any more, they have long lowercase words and numbers

Comment: if you just want to copy the active data from live to staging then you no longer need to find and enter the database names, you can use Heroku's DATABASE_URL alias.  See Takehiro Mouri's answer below (or maybe above if it gets the ups it deserves)

Comment: @LucasNelson Is there any way to automate this process and run it on a schedule? I can't do so from within a Heroku dyno, since there is no access to the heroku CLI there!

Comment: Not that I know of

Comment: Can I use second `DATABASE_URL` (`heroku pg:copy your-app::DATABASE_URL DATABASE_URL -a yourapp-staging`) to transfer to to my local DB? What syntax is to select local DB (like,, user, pass, ip, port and db_name ?

Comment: It works fine but unfortunately, the process was failed I want to resume by when it got failed, any other command to continue the transfer?

Answer (score 29):

UPDATE: 
You can run this command to transfer the database from production to staging:
`heroku pg:copy your-app::DATABASE_URL DATABASE_URL -a yourapp-staging`

It will prompt you to confirm the action, and once you have done that, all of the data will be migrated.

Comment: Does this mean the db structure will be the same as in production? In other words, will it copy data only or it will re-create the db from scratch..  tables, fields?

Comment: It looks like it does a full migration of all tables and data, First dropping all the data in the staging DB.

Answer (score 17):

Here's a simple and safe solution to this using Heroku's add-on attachments and forking. It does not require backups, no downtime, and does not overwrite any database.

**You need to attach the production database to the staging app first, then fork on the staging app.** If you fork on the production app, then attach to the staging app, the billing app will be the production app and you won't be able to detach the fork from it.

**1.** First find out the add-on name of your production database (here it is `postgres-prod-123`):

```
$ heroku addons --app myapp-production
heroku-postgresql (postgresql-prod-123)  standard-0  $50/month
 └─ as DATABASE
```

**2.** Then [attach](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/646) the production database add-on to your staging app. Give it a name like `PRODUCTION_DB` to make it easy to recognize:

```
$ heroku addons:attach postgresql-prod-123 --app myapp-staging --as PRODUCTION_DB
```

**3.** Then [create a fork](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-fork#create-a-fork) of the production database on the staging app:

```
$ heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-0 --fork PRODUCTION_DB_URL --as STAGING_DB --app myapp-staging
```

**4.** Finally promote the fork to be the primary database of your staging app:

```
$ heroku pg:promote STAGING_DB --app myapp-staging
```

**Done!** Your staging app is now using a copy of your production database. *Note that your previous staging database is still there, you may want to destroy it after you've made sure everything works.*

To clean up, detach the production database from the staging app:

```
$ heroku addons:detach postgresql-prod-123 --app myapp-staging
```

Comment: best way to do it IMO

Comment: This was very helpful. It looks like you can can also fork now in the UI (in the Heroku Database page for the resource).

Comment: @BradBumbalough yes you can fork in the UI, but when I tried it forked but kept the billing app on the original app, so that didn't work. You can do most of the steps in the UI but the forking step seem to need to be done in CLI

Comment: Forking is only available for production tier servers. Hobbyists, ye be warned

Answer (score 15):

UPDATE: This no longer works. Please refer to @lucas-nelson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673630/how-do-i-transfer-production-database-to-staging-on-heroku-using-pgbackups-gett/24005476#30495448) below.

So things are even easier now .. checkout the transfer command as part of pgbackups

```
heroku pgbackups:transfer HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK sushi-staging::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE -a sushi
```

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrade-heroku-postgres-with-pgbackups#transfering-databases-between-heroku-applications

This has worked beautifully for me taking production code back to my staging site.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3850299/transfer-db-from-one-heroku-app-to-another-faster#comment46883073_24005424, it would destroy the original database, wouldn't it?

Comment: the documentation doesn't make it clear whether it will destroy some or all of the data in the destination database..  it was fast enough for me to do an alternate implementation so I did..

Comment: This is no longer works, please upvote @lucas-nelson's answer below.

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

`heroku pg:copy you-app-production::DATABASE DATABASE -a you-app-staging`

Comment: Just to clarify that only need to replace `you-app-production` and `you-app-staging`.  "DATABASE" doesn't need to be replace with anything.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this using below command

```
heroku pg:copy <production_app_name>::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_BLACK_URL OLIVE -a <staging_app_name> --confirm <staging_app_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with the same issue. According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10761977/how-do-i-fix-a-pgbackups-error-backup-url-is-invalid), the problem could be your heroku gem version. I just upgraded my version (from 2.26.2 to 2.26.6) and now it works.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by upgrading the DB. It seems the default 5MB was not enough.

Answer (score 1):

First create an up to date backup of production:

```
heroku pgbackups:capture -a productionappslug --expire
```

Find out what colour Heroku has named your database.

https://postgres.heroku.com/databases
or 
https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps/STAGINGAPPSLUG/resources

Then load the production db backup into staging (changing RED to whatever colour yours is):

```
heroku pgbackups:restore HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_RED -a stagingappslug `heroku pgbackups:url -a productionappslug`
```

**stagingappslug** and **liveappslug** are whatever shortnames your heroku apps are called.

Answer (score 1):

To transfer (copy) the *production* database (*source* database) to the *staging* database (*target* database) you will need to invoke `pg:copy` from the *target* application, referencing a *source* database.

`heroku pg:copy source-application::OLIVE HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK -a target-application`

Another example:

`heroku pg:copy my-production-app::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_OLIVE HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PINK --app my-staging-app`

To obtain the **colour names** of your databases, use:

```
heroku pg --app my-production-app
heroku pg --app my-staging-app
```

See [pg:copy](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases#4b-alternative-transfer-data-between-applications)

Answer (score 0):

After NO LUCK. (Im using heroku gem 2.31.4)
I did the following (help for the weary)

1. Login into Heroku Database console
2. Login to staging > 'settings' > PGRestore > Copy 'Connection Settings' into a text file.
3. Login to production > Snapshots, press '+' to make a new backup as of now. Then press download. Download 
   into the apps /tmp folder or whever you want.
4. Set staging to maintenance mode

   $ heroku maintenance:on
5. Run the command like so, with Connection Settings text and dump file at the end: PGPASSWORD={...bits of stuff here...} -p 5432 'tmp/b048.dump.dump'
6. After run:

   $ heroku maintenance:off
7. Login to staging and check that things match. 
   Find a recent transaction you know is in production if you can via. 
   $ heroku run console for both apps and check ids match.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not --remote its --app try this:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app production-app` --app staging-app
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

- Download the backup from heroku console and uploaded it to s3.
- `heroku pg:backups restore 'DUMP_FILE_URL_FROM_S3' DATABASE --app MY_APP`

Answer (score 0):

None, of the answers worked for me in 2023 or copied the database directly (which slowed down production for us), so I took another look at [Heroku's PGBackups documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-backups), and pieced the following together:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore `heroku pg:backups:url --app production-app | cat` DATABASE_URL --app staging-app
```

This command will get the publicly accessible backup URL of your latest backup of your production app. It will then restore that backup to your staging app.

For this command to work for you, you need to replace the name of your production and staging app. You can probably leave `DATABASE_URL` as is. It is a shorthand to identify your database, and the first one you create is called DATABASE by default. If you have multiple databases, find out the name of yours with:

```
heroku pg --app staging-app
```

and then change the command to replace the database name:

```
heroku pg:backups:restore `heroku pg:backups:url --app production-app | cat` HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT_URL --app staging-app
```